# Can websocket access devices behind firewall/router once connection is setup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, firewall

I'm wondering whether my server can access the devices behind firewall using web sockets, once the connection is established by that device (as the server is accessible by that devices)?

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484813/how-to-make-request-from-server-to-devices-behind-router), that has mentioned this same scenario, but from the answer it's not clear that whether the server can access the devices behind router or not.

If this is possible, I want to use socket.io to first initiate the connection by client to server and then making clients accessible from server to further communication.

I would have tried this by my self, but I don't have such setup available rightnow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the connection is established by the client, the server can push messages (in the end, the websocket is a TCP connection).

The only problem you might have is if the client cannot connect using websockets due to some proxy/firewall, in which case you can try secured websockets (wss). These are usually let through because the websockets layer is masked by TLS, which usually is not blocked by firewalls/proxies.

Answer (score 2):

When a client makes a webSocket connection to a server, that enables two way communication between the client and server.  Client can send packets to the server or server can send packets to the client at any time.

That does NOT enable the server to connect to any other devices on the client's network.  So, for example, if a user running a web browser loaded a web page that made a webSocket connection to your server, then your server has no more ability to connect to any other devices on that client's private network (like a printer or a computer or some other dedicated device) than it did before the webSocket connection occurred.  Thank goodness too, because that would be a huge security hole if it did.

You can, of course, use a smart client that "proxies" access to other devices.  This would likely have to be something other than a web App, but you could have a client app installed behind the firewall that connects to a server and then that server sends the client messages that it wants the client to then deliver to various devices behind the firewall.  It would essentially be asking the client to make a connection from the client to some other device behind the firewall and then do something on behalf of the server (send it data, execute some command, etc...).  There are obvious security implications/risks with doing that so it would have to be done very, very carefully to be safe.  This proxy scheme is not specific to a webSocket.  It could be done with any protocol between client and server.